# How to delete channels with nothing on them

Tags: animation, keyframes, shortcut

[image]

I've heard solutions are pressing "O" or using the clean channels button.

Pressing O turns on proportional editing and Clean Channels doesn't get rid of scale for some reason

[image]

Any known solutions?

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing on them". Channel is automatically deleted when no keyframes on a channel. What role plays Proportional editing set ON here? When you search for Clean Channels operator and hover above, tooltip says it removes closely spaced keyframes that sound weird to me. Check manual explanation https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/graph_editor/fcurves/editing.html#clean-channels but according to it it should delete channels with single keyframe (when it is not used by modifier or driver) ... what I tried now it doesn't match my expectation ... bug report?

Comment: Have you seen this Blender Add-on?
https://blendermarket.com/products/delete-static-channels